# JVM's Hot Swap of classes loaded by Spring, using JPDA

Tags: java, spring, jvm, hotswap, jpda

could please anybody share his experience about this topic ?

When using jpda on tomcat, does class reloading work even for classes loaded via spring ? Let say that I have spring context with couple of classes loaded and instantiated and I want to change a method in one of them.

In general, the class is replaced, reloaded and every other instance is instantiated from the new version of the class. I suppose that even the old instances are replaced with the old ones ?

Does this also work when Spring is used ? So that I have a mvc controller and I change its method ?

Or do I have to use JRebel for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with this is that it works well and reliably, provided you don't of course change the method signature, add fields etc. Changing the implementation of any existing method of any class in the spring container (MVC controllers included) should work entirely as expected. For reference, the last time I tested this was with Tomcat 6, Spring 3 and using Netbeans 6.9's "Apply Code Changes" over a remote attached debugger, but it's Java standard so I doubt the IDE will effect it much.

EDIT: None of the above concerns JRebel (I've never used it).

Comment: Ok, I've never been a fan of this hot swapping because mostly I was doing changes out of the allowed "hotSwap" scope. I've never needed to change a content of a method and check the results. One usually creates another method when writing something. However, considering the fact how spring context and dependency injection works, I wonder that hotswapping is working even for these classes... Maybe it is all under the JVM's hood, invisible for spring...preserving classes signatures and object references etc.

Comment: @lisak I might be wrong on this, but I believe it actually doesn't need to re-instantiate any classes as you say. The implementation of the method is at a specific memory address, and all it doesn't is update the links to that memory address to point to a different location. Hence it's quite fast and reliable, and the usage of Spring or any other library becomes a non-issue.